# How to implement singleton for use in application servers, singleton OK?

Tags: singleton, websphere

I have some code that gets run a lot (for every webservice request).

The code is called from within a web service which is hosted by an application server (Websphere 7).

I noticed Websphere uses a lot of classes that presumably are singleton objects (such as BOXMLSerializer (for de/serializing business objects) or BOFactory.

I want to save on the cost of creating a new object for every web service request for example.

Is creating a singleton that lives for the duration of the uptime of the app server is the best way of dealing with this?

Does Websphere provides any help with these sorts of things?

Answer (score 2):

erloewe is correct, an ordinary singleton could work. Regarding the Singleton Session Bean though -- it's part of the J2EE6 spec and is not available in WAS7 (since it is only J2EE5). It will be part of WAS8 though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could make an ordinary singleton. However due the way the classloader works it might not be exactly same for your applications if you had several applications requiring similar service. For that reason you probably should create a [Singleton Session Bean](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html).